windows gMSA and sMSA with desktop applications
We know how to use and configure Managed Service Account  with  windows-services and  Scheduled-batch-tasks and run the service under the security context of MSA
Can we use the MSA  for any  installed application and run the app under the security context of MSA ??
Basically my idea is this home-grown  .NET app that I have installed on my windows box wants to invoke one kerberized-network-service (s1)
So my app will need to collect a kerberos-service-ticket  of  S1
computer will help my app (running under MSA identity )  in getting service-ticket  of  S1
now my application-code can make the call to S2
Thanks.

Possibly related: GetServiceAccountPassword

You can login as a gMSA using the standard LogonUser function.  Pass SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD as the password ("_SA_{262E99C9-6160-4871-ACEC-4E61736B6F21}").  SeTcbPrivilege must be enabled at the time of the logon, and you must be running as a user with rights to access the MSA (be in PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword).  The MSA must also be granted rights to logon to the local machine in the specified manner (e.g.: secpol.msc "Log on as a service", "Log on as a batch job", "Allow log on locally").
if (!LogonUserW("gmsaname$", "DOMAIN", "_SA_{262E99C9-6160-4871-ACEC-4E61736B6F21}" /* SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD */, 
    5 /* LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE */, 0 /* LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT */, out var token))
{
    throw new Win32Exception();
}
using (token)
{
    var identity = new WindowsIdentity(token.DangerousGetHandle());
    Console.WriteLine(identity.Name);
}

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern bool LogonUserW(string pszUsername, string pszDomain, string pszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out SafeAccessTokenHandle phToken);

It's also probably possible to login directly by retrieving the password from msDS-ManagedPassword, decode it, then use it directly.
You also can do it with psexec, though I wouldn't recommend that for programmatic use.
The standard ways to run code as a gMSA are to use a NT Service, Scheduled Task, or IIS AppPool.
Related:

GetServiceAccountPasswordCalled by the LSP behind the scenes and specifes some of the requirements.
puppetlabs/puppet#9328 Windows Service Provider Doesn't Support gMSAs
How to Impersonate as Group Managed Service Account (GMSA) in Application


I see... thanks Mitch.   So what are you saying is,   if I log into the windows box as admin then  I can pull up that .NET app through  psexec
psexec.exe -i -u domain\gMSA$ -p ~ myapp.exe
Now this app's code can obtain  service-ticket of  any kerberized-service in the network which is accepting gMSA as the security-principal.
Am I right ??

You can run an app with the identity of the MSA, and access network resources granted to the MSA.  I don't think it is necessarily tied to Kerberos.  MSA's are just a plaintext password stored in LDAP, so I suspect it works with NTLM as well.

Awesome Mitch !!  thanks for confirmation.

So one follow up point,   as we are discussing and I as validated  I can spin up a my-app running under  MSA-identity as shown below.
psexec.exe -i -u domain\gMSA$ C:\myDesktopApp.exe
Instead of MSA,   if I want to run my  desktop-App under any regular service-account of my AD-domain  can I do that  ?
Basically can I put   regular service-account in above command ??
Thanks.

If you know the password to the account, yes.  You can also use runas for that, which is built in to windows.

Got it.. Thanks  Mitch.

I have one follow up question .
If I start one windows-service  using  service-account (SA1)  but then in the code of the service if I want to access some external service in network using  gMSA or  sMSA,  is it possible ??
Does windows OS allow the application/service spun with one account and use other account to complete NTLM or Kerberos authentication during network call  ?

Yes, but consider posting a separate question.  You can either use WNetAddConnection* (or a wrapper) or use impersonation.

thanks  @Mitch.  I will create a new separate question and discuss.
